# Articles and Works by Developers

Tags: time, free-time

When I'm coming to home after the work, there left about 2-3 hours to work on my own projects. Some good programmers/developers also write books/articles/etc. I'm getting angry of to little time and interested how others can do so much - work in their main job, work on own projects and write articles/books?

Do you know some formula or some technique to be able do all the mentioned?

Comment: Well it seems that you wanna prove you can do all these things rather than wanting to do all these things

Comment: I found that a bad marriage was a pretty effective driver to do anything else.

Comment: Don't sleep so much.

Comment: Don't waste precious time on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Wow. I can only dream of having 2-3 hours of spare time every day!!

Comment: How many hours a week do you work at your job?

Comment: I agree with Pong, if you have 2-3 hours of spare time each day then you don't have kids and aren't married (or are in a bad marriage, which does wonders for the workaholic in all of us). But Nike answered your question for you already. Just Do It. You'd be surprised what you can accomplish by being persistent even if it is only a small amount of time each day.

Comment: +1 on the Just Do It. At the beginning of the year I made a decision that if I had an evening in then I would spend some time on a project. Some nights I spend 5 minutes, some I spend 2 hours. I made more progress in January then the entire previous year.

Answer (score 8):

Think about all the time you spend *consuming* and replace it with *producing*. Reading newspapers -> writing blog. Playing games -> writing pet project/game. Reading books -> writing a book. Browsing art gallery -> painting. Watching TV -> making videos. And so on...

Comment: Don't replace it all, or you'll end up with nothing left to give

Comment: +1 - I know that I stopped playing games (console and computer) and have gained so much extra time. On top of that, I feel better about myself because I may have gotten very little coding done in an hour of free time, but that is still more than what I would've accomplished if I was still playing WoW (to be fair, Blizzard basically made that decision for me with the latest version of the game but I digress)

Answer (score 3):

What I know some people do (including myself, but for other reasons than programming) is that they work less than a 100% position. Getting one extra day to work on your own projects every week or even every other week makes a huge difference.